# How does Visual Studio decide whether an NMake (Makefile) project is out of date?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nmake

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with several NMake (Makefile) sub-projects. Those projects build by using the "Build Command Line" to launch a batch file. Visual Studio always thinks those projects are out of date, even if they were just built. That's not too surprising, since Visual Studio doesn't know what the batch file does.

How does Visual Studio decide whether NMake projects are out of date? I'm looking for a way to tell it that the projects are up to date, but I don't know what it checks. Turning up the build verbosity doesn't help much, because the project doesn't have any source files or output files to check and tell me which ones are out of date.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661715/added-makefile-project-to-visual-studio-2015-solution-is-always-out-of-date) has some hints, but I'm hoping someone has a conclusive answer.